# ggplot2 Plot: Change Text in Case it Exceeds the Plot Window when Exporting as PNG

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, text

I want to create a ggplot2 plot with manually specified y-lab and an annotated text within the plot. In case the y-lab/annotated text is too long, I want to replace it with a shorter text. This needs to be done automatically, since I need to perform this for a large number of plots.

Consider the following example data and text:

```
# Create example data
set.seed(123)
data <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100),
                   y = rnorm(100))

# Create two text versions
text_long <- "This is a very long text which might exceed the plot limits"
text_short <- "Short text"
```

Now, I can create and export a ggplot as follows:

```
# Load ggplot2 package
library("ggplot2")

# Create first plot
ggp1a <- ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() + 
  ylab(text_long)

# Export first plot as png
png("C:/Your-Path/my_plot1a.png", res = 300, height = 500, width = 1500)
ggp1a
dev.off()
```

[image]

At this point, I want to check whether the y-lab text was cut off. In case the text was cut off, I want to replace the text as follows:

```
# Create second plot
ggp2a <- ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() + 
  ylab(text_short) # Short text

# Export second plot as png
png("C:/Your-Path/my_plot2a.png", res = 300, height = 500, width = 1500)
ggp2a
dev.off()
```

[image]

The same problem occurs when I annotate text within the plot window:

```
# Create first plot
ggp1b <- ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() + 
  annotate("text", x = 2, y = 2, col = 2, label = text_long)

# Export first plot as png
png("C:/Your-Path/my_plot1b.png", res = 300, height = 500, width = 1500)
ggp1b
dev.off()
```

[image]

The same procedure as before. In case the text was cut off, I want to replace the text as follows:

```
# Create second plot
ggp2b <- ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() + 
  annotate("text", x = 2, y = 2, col = 2, label = text_short) # Short text

# Export second plot as png
png("C:/Your-Path/my_plot2b.png", res = 300, height = 500, width = 1500)
ggp2b
dev.off()
```

[image]

How could I replace these texts **automatically** in case they are too long?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not aware of any automatic solution. Usually I do export -> check -> fix size or length -> export -> ... Until I am satisfied. If any automatic way exists I'll be also really interested to see it

Comment: Maybe inspect the elements of your plot and find roughly how many characters the string would be to exceed the dimensions of your plot (use `str_length(ggp1a$labs$y)`).  You can then build a function with an if else statement to do it.  Though this method would likely only work with your y label.

Comment: Further to Ben's suggestion, you might want to switch to a monotype font, so that you can know for certain how many characters fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you could solve the in plot text unless it's in the same place every time, but this should work for your ylab issue.

You can make a function like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

long_short_ylab <- function(short, long) {
 if(str_length(long) > 50) { # adjust this number to whatever you figure out is your max length
   labs(y = short)
 } else {
   labs(y = long)
 }
}
```

You can then use this in your `ggplot` call like so:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() + 
  long_short_ylab(short = text_short, long = text_long)
```

[image]